# Surface had no valid native Surface error on exiting the video call

Tags: android, webrtc

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1.Tested on SamSung Galaxy TabA

2.Unable to exit One to One video call

3.Surface had no valid native Surface error on ending the video call.

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**

MarshMallow(Android 6),Samsung Galaxy TabA

**Please provide any additional information below.**

Using the below code to exit the video call:

```
    if (factory != null ) {
        factory.stopAecDump();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Closing audio source.");
    if (audioSource != null) {
        audioSource.dispose();
        audioSource = null;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping capture.");
    if (videoCapturer != null) {
        try {
            videoCapturer.stopCapture();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        videoCapturer.dispose();
        videoCapturer = null;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Closing video source.");
    if (videoSource != null) {
        videoSource.dispose();
        videoSource = null;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Closing peer connection factory.");
    if (factory != null) {
        factory.dispose();
        factory = null;
    }
    if(localSurfaceView != null && localSurfaceView.isEnabled() )localSurfaceView.release();
    if(remoteSurfaceView != null && remoteSurfaceView.isEnabled())remoteSurfaceView.release();
```

**Log:**

E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeGetSurfaceId: Could not retrieve native Surface from surface.

E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1: Received exception on GL render thread: 
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface had no valid native Surface.

at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.nativeGetSurfaceId(Native Method)

at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceId(LegacyCameraDe vice.java:658)

at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceIds(LegacyCameraDevice.java:667)
                                                                             at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:715)

at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager)

at E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-4811-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned

10-17 18:10:31.288 4811-4824/com.caprusit.capv E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-4811-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned

Comment: I am not clear what are you trying to achieve here .So try to use finish(); in the process.

Comment: What the main reason for the error Surface had no valid native Surface error?

Comment: This is the issue related to WebRtc video calling

Comment: Any news on this topic?